# shortening key names in a json object using python/bash

Tags: python, json, bash, sed

this is a function I have written that will change/shorten all the keys on a json object

```
function replaceKeyWithNewKey(jsonObj, new_keys, old_keys){
        console.log("test")
        for(i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){

            for(el in jsonObj){
                //console.log(new_keys[el])
                jsonObj[i][new_keys[el]]=jsonObj[i][old_keys[el]] //add new key
                delete jsonObj[i][old_keys[el]] // delete old key
            }
        }

        return jsonObj
    }
```

What I am looking for is a way to do this in the terminal using bash or python or other, but I would like to do it in the terminal. So I would run the script on a file.json and the result would be file2.json with file2.json have the shorter keynames. **How can I do this?**

For bash I was thinking of using `sed` but I don't think that will be as good as I might replace values I don't want to replace.
The little of python I know might be the way to go.

Here is a console printout:

```
    >data[0]
    Object {Rec_Open_Date: "2016-07-07", MSISDN: 123, IMEI: 223, Data_Volume_Bytes: "673", Device_Manufacturer: "Samsung Korea"…}
    >old_keys=Object.keys(data[0])
    ["Rec_Open_Date", "MSISDN", "IMEI", "Data_Volume_Bytes", "Device_Manufacturer", "Device_Model", "Product_Description", "Data_Volume_MB"]
    >new_keys=["r", "m", "i", "d", "f", "l", "s", "d2"]
    ["r", "m", "i", "d", "f", "l", "s", "d2"]
    >function replaceKeyWithNewKey(jsonObj, new_keys, old_keys){
        console.log("test")
        for(i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){

            for(el in jsonObj){
                //console.log(new_keys[el])
                jsonObj[i][new_keys[el]]=jsonObj[i][old_keys[el]] //add new key
                delete jsonObj[i][old_keys[el]] // delete old key
            }
        }

        return jsonObj
    }
    undefined
    > replaceKeyWithNewKey(data, new_keys, old_keys)
    VM129:2 test
    [Objectd: "673"d2: "0.000641823"f: "Samsung Korea"i: 223l: "Samsung GT-I9505"m: 123r: "2016-07-07"s: "PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"__proto__: Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

here is sample data to test my function on:

```
var json = '[{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb","email":"user1@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 1"},{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc","email":"user2@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 2"}]';
```

Comment: Since you've already written code to do this in JavaScript, why don't you stick with that? (Why switch languages?)

Comment: What does this have to do with sed (as tagged)?

Comment: @smarx because I want it in a file format. whereas js i have formatted part, maybe I just need to write the read from file and  write to file part and then workout how to do this in the terminal or otherway. would like to know how to do this if you could briefly explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to load json's into a python data structure. The sample data you have given will be a python `list` of `dict`s. I think the most straightforward way is to build a dictionary mapping the old-keys to the new-keys and then iterating through the list using dictionary comprehensions to rebuild the `dict`s with new key-names from the key-name map you've built. Using your sample:

```
In [8]: jobj = [{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb","email":"user1@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 1"},{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc","email":"user2@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 2"}]

In [9]: keymap = {'email':'e', 'image':'img', 'name':'n', '_id':'id'}

In [10]: for i in range(len(jobj)):
     ...:     jobj[i] = {keymap[k]:jobj[i][k] for k in jobj[i]}
     ...: 

In [11]: jobj
Out[11]: 
[{'e': 'user1@gmail.com',
  'id': '5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb',
  'img': 'some_image_url',
  'n': 'Name 1'},
 {'e': 'user2@gmail.com',
  'id': '5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc',
  'img': 'some_image_url',
  'n': 'Name 2'}]
```

**Edit to Add**

If you want to make sure all the keys stay in order, you need to used `OrderedDict` from `collections`

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

keymap = {'email':'e', 'image':'img', 'name':'n', '_id':'id'}

with open('ordered_example.json') as f:
    jobj = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)


for i in range(len(jobj)):
    jobj[i] = OrderedDict((keymap[k],jobj[i][k]) for k in jobj[i])

print(jobj)
```

Output:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', '5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb'),
              ('e', 'user1@gmail.com'),
              ('img', 'some_image_url'),
              ('n', 'Name 1')]),
 OrderedDict([('id', '5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc'),
              ('e', 'user2@gmail.com'),
              ('img', 'some_image_url'),
              ('n', 'Name 2')])]
```

Comment: tks, anyway to keep the order of `jobj` the same as `keymap`?

Comment: @HattrickNZ yes, you need to use `OrderedDict`s. See my edit.

Comment: tks, and i like the way you added your edit and did not overwrite your initial post!

Comment: sorry but how do i edit this so that i can handle if `keymap` is an `OrderedDict`? `>>> headers
['email', 'image', 'name', '_id']
>>> new_keys
['e', 'img', 'n', 'id']
>>> keymap=[OrderedDict(zip(headers,new_keys))]
>>> keymap
[OrderedDict([('email', 'e'), ('image', 'img'), ('name', 'n'), ('_id', 'id')])]` as the for loop won't work, I get `list indices must be integers, not unicode`

Comment: think i got it tks `jobj[i] = OrderedDict((keymap[0][k],jobj[i][k]) for k in jobj[i])`. I needed there xero element here `keymap[0][k]`.

Comment: There is no need to make `keymap` an `OrderedDict`. There is even *less* need to make it the single element of a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be manipulating `JSON` from the command-line, I recommend installing [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

You can put your key map in an associative array in bash 4+, something like this:

```
declare -A map=([foobar]=foo [poohbah]=pooh [zoowicky]=zoo)
```

And loop through it to build a `jq` script to replace the keys.

```
jq_script=
for old in "${!map[@]}"; do
  new="${map[$old]}"
  jq_script+="${jq_script:+|}if has(\"$old\") then { \"$new\": .[\"$old\"] } + del(.[\"$old\"]) else . end"
done
```

which you run like this:

```
jq "$jq_script" <old.json >new.json
```

On my sample JSON:

```
{
  "foobar": 1,
  "zoowicky": 3,
  "different": 4
}
```

which doesn't have all of the keys in the map and does have a key not in the map, it produces this result:

```
{
  "zoo": 3,
  "foo": 1,
  "different": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using sed to substitute the keys.

```
#!/bin/bash

function replaceKeyWithNewKey() {

    json_file="$1"
    old_key="$2"
    new_key="$3"

    # you'd better to backup first.
    sed -i "" "s/${old_key}/${new_key}/g" ${json_file}
}

old_keys=("Rec_Open_Date" "MSISDN" "IMEI" "Data_Volume_Bytes" "Device_Manufacturer" "Device_Model" "Product_Description" "Data_Volume_MB")

new_keys=("r" "m" "i" "d" "f" "l" "s" "d2")

# input json file
json_file="input"

for ((i = 0; i < ${#old_keys[@]}; ++i)) do
    replaceKeyWithNewKey ${json_file} "${old_keys[$i]}" "${new_keys[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: If you want backups, don't pass an empty argument to `sed -i`.

Comment: every time the function replace the old key will be backup.. so can not just using this to backup the original file.